# Android Firebase cannot download images and add them to a Bitmap Array

Tags: firebase, kotlin, bitmap, firebase-storage

I am currently working on a matching card game where I need to store the images on Firebase. I am uploading the images by a button click when I start the game(doing it automatically creates same problem but the button one is safer) I think the Image isn't getting downloaded fast enough to show on the card face or it might not be working in a sequence with the whole app so the bitmap array gets zero elements inside. My current code is:

```
class game2x2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var buttons: List<ImageButton>
    //private lateinit var bitmapArray: ArrayList<Bitmap>
    private var bitmapArray = mutableListOf<Bitmap>()
    private lateinit var button1: ImageButton
    private lateinit var button2: ImageButton
    private lateinit var button3: ImageButton
    private lateinit var button4: ImageButton
    private lateinit var upload: Button
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game2x2)

        val min = 1
        val max = 45
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val imageID1 = Random().nextInt(max - min + 1) + min
        val imageID2 = Random().nextInt(max - min + 1) + min
        val aDatabase = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("all/$imageID1.jpg")
        val sDatabase = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("all/$imageID2.jpg")

        upload = findViewById(R.id.uploadButton)
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.imageButton1)
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2)
        button3 = findViewById(R.id.imageButton3)
        button4 = findViewById(R.id.imageButton4)
        buttons = listOf(button1, button2, button3, button4)

        upload.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            try {
                val localfile = File.createTempFile("tempfile", ".jpg")
                aDatabase.getFile(localfile).addOnSuccessListener {
                    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localfile.absolutePath)
                    bitmapArray.add(bitmap)
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.w("myapplication", "ERROR RETRIEVING IMAGE")
                    Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR RETRIEVING IMAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            try {
                val localfile = File.createTempFile("tempfile1", ".jpg")
                sDatabase.getFile(localfile).addOnSuccessListener {
                    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localfile.absolutePath)
                    bitmapArray.add(bitmap)
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.w("myapplication", "ERROR RETRIEVING IMAGE")
                    Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR RETRIEVING IMAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            ///    DUPLICATE
            bitmapArray.addAll(bitmapArray)
            ///SHUFFLE
            bitmapArray.shuffle()
            Log.w("myapplication", bitmapArray.size.toString())
        })

        buttons.forEachIndexed { index, button ->
            button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                button.setImageBitmap(bitmapArray[index])
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to retrieve image from the Firebase Storage besides downloading and adding it to a temporary file and then decoding it to a bitmap?

I tried anything that I could find. I even tried adding the access tokens of the images to a realtime database and then getting them from there but I failed terribly. Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getFile()` an asynchronous task I would imagine your log statement `Log.w("myapplication", bitmapArray.size.toString())` is executing while the bitmapArray is still empty? This would happen because the `aDatabase.getFile().addOnSuccessListener {}` and `sDatabase.getFile().addOnSuccessListener {}` won't execute until the download finishes, but allow the rest of your function to continue to execute.

What you need to do is await the results of the downloads before continuing with the duplicate and shuffle portions.

`getFile()` returns a [`FileDownloadTask`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/storage/FileDownloadTask), which inherits from [`StorageTask`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageTask). `StorageTask` has an `isComplete()` method -- and a few others the may be useful for errors cases. One option would be to capture the `FileDownloadTask` in a variable and not continue executing until your downloads are finished. However, be warned this might freeze up your main thread.

Edit: Instead of checking status on the main thread, you might want to try something like disabling the buttons until the images are ready. See edit comments:

```
class game2x2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var buttons: List<ImageButton>
    //private lateinit var bitmapArray: ArrayList<Bitmap>
    private var bitmapArray = mutableListOf<Bitmap>()
    private lateinit var button1: ImageButton
    private lateinit var button2: ImageButton
    private lateinit var button3: ImageButton
    private lateinit var button4: ImageButton

    private val numImages = 2 // EDIT total number of images we need to download
    private val numImagesReady = AtomicInteger(0) // EDIT count of how many images are currently ready

    private lateinit var upload: Button
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game2x2)

        val min = 1
        val max = 45
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val imageID1 = Random().nextInt(max - min + 1) + min
        val imageID2 = Random().nextInt(max - min + 1) + min
        val aDatabase = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("all/$imageID1.jpg")
        val sDatabase = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("all/$imageID2.jpg")

        upload = findViewById(R.id.uploadButton)
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.imageButton1)
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2)
        button3 = findViewById(R.id.imageButton3)
        button4 = findViewById(R.id.imageButton4)
        buttons = listOf(button1, button2, button3, button4)

        // EDIT disable buttons until all images are ready
        buttons.forEach {
            it.setEnabled(false)
        }

        upload.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            try {
                val localfile = File.createTempFile("tempfile", ".jpg")
                aDatabase.getFile(localfile).addOnSuccessListener {
                    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localfile.absolutePath)
                    bitmapArray.add(bitmap)


                    // EDIT add the image twice here instead of duplicating later
                    bitmapArray.add(bitmap)

                    // EDIT count this image as ready
                    val totalImagesReady = numImagesReady.incrementAndGet()
                    
                    // EDIT once all images are ready, shuffle and enable the buttons
                    if (totalImagesReady == numImages) {
                        bitmapArray.shuffle()
                        buttons.forEach { it.setEnabled(true) }
                    }


                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.w("myapplication", "ERROR RETRIEVING IMAGE")
                    Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR RETRIEVING IMAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            try {
                // SUGGESTION especially if this will be implemented 8x8, you might want to try implementing this in a loop instead of duplicating code
                val localfile = File.createTempFile("tempfile1", ".jpg")
                sDatabase.getFile(localfile).addOnSuccessListener {
                    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localfile.absolutePath)
                    bitmapArray.add(bitmap)

                    // EDIT add the image twice here instead of duplicating later
                    bitmapArray.add(bitmap)

                    // EDIT count this image as ready
                    val totalImagesReady = numImagesReady.incrementAndGet()
                    
                    // EDIT once all images are ready, shuffle and enable the buttons
                    if (totalImagesReady == numImages) {
                        bitmapArray.shuffle()
                        buttons.forEach { it.setEnabled(true) }
                    }


                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.w("myapplication", "ERROR RETRIEVING IMAGE")
                    Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR RETRIEVING IMAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
// EDIT moved            ///    DUPLICATE
// EDIT refactor         bitmapArray.addAll(bitmapArray)
// EDIT moved            ///SHUFFLE
// EDIT moved            bitmapArray.shuffle()
// EDIT remove           Log.w("myapplication", bitmapArray.size.toString())
        })

        buttons.forEachIndexed { index, button ->
            button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                button.setImageBitmap(bitmapArray[index])
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes the log returns 0 but when I press the button again it returns 4 as it should. Is there any way that you can show me how can I make the program wait until the downloads are finished because the start is a 2x2 game I will go up to  an 8x8 game. I think I tried every way possible and it still gives me errors. I would be very glad if you can help me out on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious time. I will update this once I implement your code to mine.